# How to add points at infinity for a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

my understanding is to add a line which parallel to something of this curve
however what is this something, can it be a tangent line

is this understanding correct? if not, where is this point in order to complete projective space?

Comment: Are you thinking of an elliptic curve, say to have the neutral element of the group?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but I think the geometric picture you're looking for is that the points "at infinity" of a curve ( informally ) correspond to lines such that the tangent of the curve approaches that line as you go to infinity, up to parallelism ( ie two parallel lines are the same).  Thus, a straight line would have just one point at infinity, but so would a parabola, or the graph of $y=x^3$.

Comment: how this point or line complete projective space?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking why these lines correspond to the closure of the curve in projective space?

Comment: not sure, could you elaborate this, i know closure is substitute x1/x0, x2/x0 into x, y

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in GAP, or was that tag not supposed to be there?

Comment: I've removed the `gap` tag - that is a tag for questions related to the [computational algebra system GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) so it's not relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to learn some projective geometry.  There are plenty of sources for this sort of thing.  Here are some notes by Nigel Hitchin I found that look good:

http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/hitchinnotes/hitchinnotes.html